# Can we "integrate" functors?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, derived-functors

Let $F:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}'$ be a functor between "nice" (e.g. abelian with enough injectives) categories. If F is not exact we can form the derived functors $F',F'',...$
Is it possible to reverse this process ("integrate" $F$) or stated reversely: Are there nice conditions on a functor $F$ to be a derived functor?

Comment: Yoneda observed that $L_p(F)(A) = \text{Nat}(\text{Ext}^p(\text{hom}_A), F)$, this might be helpful.

Comment: Could you explain what $L_p$ is? And do you mean $\text{Ext}^p(\text{hom}_A)$ to be $Ext^p(\underline{       },A)$?

Comment: @Takirion, I guess in this context $L_p$ is the left derivation of functors (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_functor#Variations)). So $L_p(F)$ is the derived functor, which you can apply to an object A.

Comment: Ah, yes, this seems plausible.